# CSS/HTML behavior in Android and Chrome

Tags: android, html, css

I have a CSS/HTML problem in my android browser. If you visit this page in a desktop browser and you resize your browser just like the size of a smartphone (700px or less width) it displays properly. But when I tried to browse this page in an android browser, it has a white space on the right, which is really annoying. I don't know what causes this but I do hope someone here knows.

Here's an example of the page.

shopaholiq.jehzhost.com/clothing/pulling-strings.html (Please check in a resized desktop browser (Portrait form) and Android browser in Portrait).

I have attached two examples to clearly show my problem.
Android Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1mvw.png
Chrome Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yoyq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your body.
That's all.

Comment: Wow! that worked like magic. I wish I could up vote u but my rep is not enough. Thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: @jehzlau you are welcome, stackoverflow is a place for us to help and learn from each other, not for earning reputations :) Happy coding.

Comment: thank you so much for your willingness to help. This saved me around $50.00 USD. Somebody at freelancer.com offered to fix it for $50.00. Hahaha. But the solution is just hiding the overflow and I never thought it was that easy. Thanks again! :D

Comment: @jehzlau no problem mate, I believe the joy is more than just to save some money because you also learn from stackoverflow and this becomes your own knowledge.

Comment: Yeah! I've been learning a lot here. Next time, if I gained more knowledge, I will help newbies like myself. :D